# Strange behavior on loopback hasMany relation

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I have a loopback model (products) in a MongoDb database with a hasMany relation with another model (systems):

```
"relations": {
"systems": {
  "type": "hasMany",
  "model": "systems",
  "foreignKey": "productId"
}
```

},

When I use an include filter on the products service I get an array of systems:

```
{
"name": "SAP BW  7.3 Business Warehouse",
"active": true,
"id": "56a127823967cdb263edf682",
"systems": 
[
  {
   "sid": "AB1",
   "description": "IBM SAP ERP ECC 6.04 ABAP",
   productId": "56a127823967cdb263edf682"
  },
  {
   "sid": "BW5",
   "description": "BW5 - BW 7.0/SEM 6.0 - Bus Intel",
   productId": "56a127823967cdb263edf682"
  }
]
},
```

Which is what I want.  However, when I update the productId in systems to "" the output from the service above doesn't change. It still includes the same systems even though the records in the MongoDB systems collection shows productId is "".

```
{
  sid: "AB1",
  description: "IBM SAP ERP ECC 6.04 ABAP",
  productId: "",
  id: "56a127a93967cdb263edf69c",
},
```

At first I thought it might be a cache issue in the browser but I tried a different browser and got the same result.  Could it be a cache in Mongo?

Thanks,

Ross

UPDATE:  I think I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of the hasMany relation.  I have another product instance which returns this:

```
{
  name: "SAP ERP GBI Intro to ERP 2.40 (SCC)",
  id: "56a127823967cdb263edf684",
  systems: [
  {
    sid: "BK1",
    description: "SAP ERP GLOBAL BIKE V2.30",
    productId: "56a127823967cdb263edf684",
    id: "56a127a93967cdb263edf6aa"
  },
  {
    sid: "BK3",
    description: "SAP ERP GLOBAL BIKE V2.30",
    id: "56a127a93967cdb263edf6ac"
  },
  {
   sid: "BK1",
   description: "SAP ERP GLOBAL BIKE V2.30",
   productId: "56a127823967cdb263edf684",
   id: "56a127a93967cdb263edf6aa"
  }
]
},
```

So it has the same instance of system twice.  That suggests that the data describing the relationship between the two collections is stored somewhere and it isn't being dynamically created when the query is executed.

I also tried the DELETE endpoint:

http://localhost:3000/api/products/56a127823967cdb263edf682/systems

Even though it returns 204 as expected, it systems are still returned when querying the product.

It seems to me that something is broken.

Comment: Yes, for some reason Strongloop decided to cache relationships queries by default. I'm currently looking for a solution to this as well.